# Reserved Keyword in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider the following setup

```
create table #test([user] varchar(10))
insert into #test([user]) values ('test')
```

when `user` column is enclosed with square brackets then the query returns result else it does not return result even though there is a matching record

```
SELECT *
FROM   #test WHERE [user] = 'test' -- returns record

SELECT *
FROM   #test WHERE user = 'test' --did not return record
```

This begs the following two questions

1. Why is the first query works and the second query does not ?
2. Why the reserved keyword is allowed to use in `where` clause without escaping it ?

Comment: Because [`USER` is a very special value](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/user-transact-sql). It does, actually, return something when you don't escape it. It's just not going to be `test`. Try `select user, [user] from #test` and see.

Comment: Just because the keyword is reserved doesn't mean you are prevented from running a query. SQL is not strict like that. But yes, "user" is a reserved word so SQL server assumes you are talking about a literal SQL user unless you wrap it in brackets to denote a column.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Cheers!! never know that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User is a reserved keyword for a reason. Try this:

```
SELECT User;
```

For me, it returns a single row with value `dbo`.

So the query without escaping `user` is perfectly valid, it just doesn't fit the value you are comparing it to.

Answer (score 5):

As per  [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-transact-sql)

`user` without brackets will work as function which returns database user name

if you check with following query it will return records

```
SELECT *
FROM   #test WHERE user = 'dbo'
```

When we Use `[]` Square brackets it sql server will treat as non reserve keyword like user defined column name,table name,function name.etc

Comment: Didn't see that coming. Cheers